# What are the locations on the Boeing 737 wing where the airfoil changes?

Tags: boeing-737, airfoil

I would like to know where along the span of the 737 (let's say the NG) wing the two midsection airfoils are used. I am planning on running a CFD analysis of the 737 wing, and I need accurate data.